# How do you check if the datetime column in a pandas dataframe belong to the same date for every row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe, how do I check if all the rows have the same date in the time column?

```
index                       time  bid_size     bid     ask     ask_size  
6      2019-01-07 07:45:03.000117        31  152.54  152.55       105   
7      2019-01-07 07:45:03.174649        30  152.54  152.55       107   
8      2019-01-07 07:45:03.217824        29  152.54  152.55       107   
9      2019-01-07 07:45:03.315518        28  152.54  152.55       107   
10     2019-01-07 07:45:06.234752        32  152.54  152.55        98   
11     2019-01-07 07:45:10.110597        42  152.54  152.55       112   
12     2019-01-07 07:45:10.126952        51  152.53  152.54         6   
13     2019-01-07 07:45:10.127742        38  152.53  152.54         6   
14     2019-01-07 07:45:10.173779        33  152.53  152.54         6   
15     2019-01-07 07:45:10.301095        35  152.53  152.54         6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for scalar:

```
print (df.time.dt.date.nunique() == 1)
True
```

Or [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for check  if all values are dupes:

```
print (df.time.dt.date.duplicated(keep=False))
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
9    True
Name: time, dtype: bool
```